# Passing value from MainActivity to Broadcast Receiver using SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-sharedpreferences

I am new to android programming and I am trying to build an app which changes the profile on receiving a message from the user. The app basically has one `activity` and a `broadcast receiver`. I am prompting the user to set a password for changing the profile and the password is saved in a `Shared Preference` which I am using inside `MainActivity`. I am not able to retrieve the password stored in `shared preference` in the `broadcast receiver` class.Also, I can only use `Shared Preference` for storing the password.The code for `MainActivity` , `Broadcast Receiver` , layout and `Android manifest` file is given below. Thanks a lot for your help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



public EditText setPass;
public Button submit;
public static String password;


SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
boolean b=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setPass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.setPassEditId);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButtonId);

    sharedPreferences= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Pritom",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            password=setPass.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("password",password);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password saved successfully"+password,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //b=sharedPreferences.contains("password")?true:false;
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"b:"+b,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}
```

}

Here,in `MainActivity` class the variable `b` returns true which means that the `shared preference` exists.

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public AudioManager audioManager;
public String me = "";
public String last = "";
public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
boolean b = false;



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Pritom", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String pass3 = sharedPreferences.getString("password", null);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "n";

                String smsBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

                if (smsBody.equals("@general" + pass3)) {
                    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audioManager.setRingerMode(audioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    } 
}
```

The problem here is that `pass3` which retrieves the value from `shared preference` returns nothing for which the `if` statement for checking the message does not work.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: ***I am retrieving the password inside the Shared Preference in the broadcast receiver, but I am not able to retrieve it*** ....well,a little bit confusing...can you clearify?

Comment: I think the problem is that your activity and broadcast receiver are accessing two different shared preferences files. Try to use `context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(....)` inside the broadcast receiver.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, I have updated my question.

Comment: @Titus, do I have to use `context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences()` in both my `activity` and `receiver` ?

Comment: I think it will work if you only add it in the broadcast receiver. The context passed to `onReceive(...)` differs based on who is calling the broadcast receiver.

Comment: @Titus, In the receiver class I added this line : `sharedPreferences = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Pritom", context.MODE_PRIVATE);` , but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Inside onReceive method
sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Pritom", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Instead of this line, use
sharedPreferences= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Pritom", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: This code is working, maybe you have not store the password in shared preference.

Comment: I have stored the password in `shared preference` , which is why I have written the code : `editor.putString("password",password);` and `editor.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility that you receives broadcast before setting up password.
Broadcast receiver registered on SMS received that means it calls when SMS received.

What when sms is received and you still don't assign password to shared preference? In that case you are not able to get password from preference.

Please check that scenario and make some changes to that.

Comment: What should I do in that case?

Comment: This is first time password setting right? @PritomMazumdar

Comment: Yes this is the first time

Comment: You can try dummy password or consider it as null and do your stuff

Comment: I have tried all of that, dummy password and null but nothing works, I even uninstalled the app and re-installed it but still no luck :(

Comment: Can you please explain why you have written this : if (smsBody.equals("@general" + pass3))
And what does it mean?

Comment: I tried to implement this app for when the mobile is in general,silent and vibrate mode. So for general I have written @general inside the `if` statement. But for testing purpose you can remove "@general".

Comment: your smsBody is equal to your password?

Comment: No according to the given program `smsbody` is equal to `@general` + `my_password` , e.g., `smsbody` is equal to `@generalabcde` where `abcde` is the password I will set.

Comment: when you send SMS?

Comment: When I send SMS the `smsbody` is the same as described in the earlier comment.

Comment: Please make sure you have set password before receiving SMS. Please debug app and check what actually happens.

Comment: I have done that, I have first set the password and then I send an sms